# a basic keystroke map

Tags: windows, dictionary, keystroke

I downloaded AutoHotKey today and read the tutorial.  What I want to do is have an F2 key do a shift-ctrl-S in one application.  I cannot figure out how to do that by reading the tutorial.  How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, install autohotkey on your system.

Once installed, create a text file and save it as .ahk (rather than .txt).

Within the file, at the end, type the following code:

```
F2::Send +^s
```

Save the file then double click it to run the program.

This will change F2 to your shift-control-s in ALL applications.

To make it application-specific, when running, right click on the icon in the taskbar and choose "Windows Spy". Click into the application you want to use the F2 shortcut in and make a note of the line just below `>>>>>>>>>>( Window Title & Class )<<<<<<<<<<<`

Now, change your script to this:

```
#IfWinActive INSERTWindowsSpyWindowTitleHERE
F2::Send +^s
#IfWinActive
```

Obviously making sure to change `INSERTWindowsSpyWindowTitleHERE` to what you got from windows spy.

Save and run your script. Autohotkey will now only make F2 do that shortcut when the window (found via Windows spy) is active. (The last `#IfWinActive` is used to "reset" checking for that window in code below where this is typed - useful if you're going to type more autohotkey code in the future)